# Enable Virtualization In Hyper-V

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v-server-2012

I need to run OpenStack on Hyper-V for test environments. Where to enable running hypervisor applications on Hyper-V. Help me please.

Comment: What research have you done already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SImple: YOU DO NOT. Running a hypervisor in a hypervisor is generally not supported - there are some exceptions but those are specific to a product IIRC and come with a performance cost.

High-Performance Hypervisors need special support by the chip and that gets locked by the hypervisor - it is generally not made to support "chains of virtualzation" because they are pretty much not needed in a professional environment.

The only scenarios this may make sense is:

- Testing a hypervisor (when you develop it) and wanting to do so in an easy to wipe environment
- Being unprofessionally cheap, i.e. getting a small VPS and trying to run multiple VM's in it, or something along the line.

Otherwise you have access to the hardware and just run multiple VM's. The need to run "OpenStack on Hyper-V" is something like "Help my bypass a limitation of my architecture". It is not a good approach.

Comment: It does say that he wants it for test environments. I guess he's going to just learn how to use OpenStack by deploying some test machines on Hyper-V.

Comment: But still - a pro environment would have test machines for that. The scenario where you try out virtualization hardware nahd have no access to some (even lower power) test machines is just extremely rare.

Comment: I need to run it just for test environments.

Comment: Then take on of you test machines. As I said - it is unusual a scenario not to have access to some test physical servers.

Comment: I need to run it to learn how to use it

Comment: Ah, then this is off topic here? Not relevant to "Professional system administration"?

Comment: This is called nested virtualization, and [recent Intel chips](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Level_Address_Translation) (since Nehalem!) most certainly _do_ support it. VMware supports it from ESXi 6.0, Xen supports it from 4.4, but Microsoft does not support it in Hyper-V.

Comment: Microsoft supports it in the Hyper-V version coming 2016.

Answer (score -1):

**Hyper-V** is a **Windows Server 2012 role** which you can install via the **Server Manager**.

Once you've installed it, you can create virtual machines.

Good luck with OpenStack.